# How to reference a gist stylesheet in another gist?

Tags: github, gist

I created a gist that has a html page and a css file. How would I reference the css file in the html page?

I tried a few ways but none of them seems working. The html page is at: https://gist.github.com/yuipcheng/943286be35fd690f499d59534281a6c5

Viewing page: https://gistpreview.github.io/?943286be35fd690f499d59534281a6c5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gistpreview.github.io](https://github.com/gistpreview/gistpreview.github.io) loads the html with Javascript by using the [Github Gist API](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#get-a-gist). From [the source code](https://github.com/gistpreview/gistpreview.github.io/blob/master/main.js#L71-L72) it just writes the html content. So, it doesn't deal with relative links that may link to other css files.

You would need to :

- fork the [gistpreview](https://github.com/gistpreview/gistpreview.github.io) project
- after the html rendering (`document.write`), iterate over the `link` tags and check if they are present in the `files` field of the API result
- load the css content dynamically if matching

I've tested this method above using [this fork](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/gistpreview.github.io).

Example for you gist: https://bertrandmartel.github.io/gistpreview.github.io/?943286be35fd690f499d59534281a6c5

Code before :

```javascript
var content = info.files[fileName].content;
document.write(content);
```

Code after :

```javascript
var content = info.files[fileName].content;
document.write(content);

//load links
var links = document.querySelectorAll("link");
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(info.files)) {
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var href = links[i].getAttribute("href").replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '');
    if (value.filename === href && value.type === "text/css") {
      console.log("load file " + value.filename);
      var style = document.createElement('style');
      style.type = 'text/css';
      style.innerHTML = value.content;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
    }
  }
}
```